# How to combine multiple CSV files by the matching contents

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I have two csv. first one is for PC info.(pcinfo.csv)

[image]

R1234 has two PCs

Second one is for User-mail info(mail.csv)

[image]

R9876 has no mail address

I want to make master CSV based on User ID like as below;

[image]

`$doc1 = import-csv c:\pcinfo.csv`

`$doc2 = import-csv c:\mail.csv`

`$outfile = import-csv c:\mail.csv`

`Compare-Object $doc1 $doc2 -Property ID -passthru | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Select PCname, ID, Mail | Export-csv "c:\complete.csv" -NoTypeInfo`

And it did not work properly

Comment: and there are some the other columns in PCinfo.CSV

Comment: How would you tell the difference between Apple and Dell? They share the same ID.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\pcinfo.csv |Join (Import-Csv .\mail.csv) -on ID`

Comment: Thank you but It did not work properly...